# desktop client web server, chat application

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, servlets, livechat

can any one give me guide line for making desktop client and and web server chat application. I have to do this project in java(both side client and server), for server side i am doing work in Jsp/servlet with tomcat, but how to make client application communicate with web server and if two clients want to chat what would be the best approach to follow...?

Comment: Didn't [Google](http://www.google.com) help?

Comment: If you are using TOmcat you dont need a desktop client, the browser will be our client then.

Comment: bro i did but i found urlconnection classes. problem is you have to make connection for every request from client side... secondly for accomplishing chat this approach is not effective.

Comment: @MeNoMore....requirements are to make it on desktop application.. There are some more functionalities which could not be achieved in browser that's why i have to go with desktop side... but in desktop side my main concern is with chatting..? if any can provide some guide line it will be great.

Comment: What functionalities should the desktop site do? can you point to a specific problem? its too abstract somehow.

Comment: @MeNoMore...it's basically is intera-office communication system over web server so if one user is not in office he can communicate with office members. User must have a light widget type of interface always running in front of him to communicate with his office members. Requirements are to implement it on desktop

Comment: can you not using Skype or MSN? they are much better than whatever you are going to implement.

Comment: they are not trusty ones...... this is explanation by the person who wants this system to be implement...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two common designs, i.e [Client pull](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pull_technology) and [server push](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology). Each has its own merit and disadvantages.

Client pull requires you to make periodic request to server which may cause traffic load on the server but it is easier to implement.

Server push requires you to have a "server" running on client side waiting for target server to push the message. This sounds more efficient but if you have million of clients connecting to your server, you are likely to have a large number of connections (ports) opened all the time which can be a waste of resource. This is more difficult to implement since you will need to make a client-side server as well.

Comment: In my case number of clients is not a big problem.. Can you give me an example/link how to implement server push?

Comment: have a look at https://netty.io/

Comment: ok brother i will look at it and leave comment on it for future... Thanks a lot for helping.